# How does Apple's app review work?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

If I submit multiple apps to be reviewed at once, is it possible for them to all be reviewed at the same time or do they go down the list and review the next one only after the one before it has been reviewed?

Comment: no one really knows Apple SOPs. but I would go out on a limb and say it is a queue system like at the DMV where each app pulls a different number. If you upload them quickly and no one else uploads it than you might get them reviewed at the same time. on the other hand it could be different departments review your app based off of what they are submitted in category-wise

Comment: are they somehow linked? one app needs the next one ect..

Comment: They are treated separately.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is if you put 10 or 30 apps in for review, you might [and probably should] have a hold or slowdown, but for only two apps, I doubt there is any meaningful delay by having more than one app in the queue.

See the [published app submission guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW1) on Apple's developer web site. It also mattes if you are [submitting an update](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1) as opposed to initial submission of an app for initial review and first sale.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of review, both apps are completely independent, as if they had been uploaded by two different accounts.

Different people can review the different apps, but basically you don't need to worry about uploading two apps — Apple takes care of it all for you.